# Add attribute to the checkbox field based on initial django form

Tags: django, django-forms

```
class MyForm(Form):
    real = BooleanField()
```

If `MyForm(data={'real': 'on'})`, I want to render `<input type="checkbox" checked=checked data-initial='on'>`.

If `MyForm(data={})`, I want to render `<input type="checkbox">`.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to overwrite init of MyForm class:

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    real = forms.BooleanField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = kwargs.pop('data')
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if data != {} and 'real' in data:
            self.fields['real'] = forms.BooleanField(initial=True, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'data-initial': data['real']}))
```

so if `real` is passed as key in `data` dict it will make `real` field initialy True (checked) and value will be pass to `data-initial` attr.